# Fast way to start selfhosted WCF service used for communication with native api

Tags: wcf, iis, native, unmanaged, netnamedpipebinding

I'm working on a component used for generation of 3D CAD models. Since the api used to generate the model itself is native, I'm sticking with WCF/NetNamedPipeBinding for IPC. The component is being used by a webapplication (IIS). The client proxy itself starts the service host as a own process(!). Reason behind this, is that the native API needs to "run" in its own memory in order to provide a uncorrupted 3D model. Hence WebApplication (IIS) -> WCF Proxy Client -> WCF ServiceHost in its own process (EXE, self hosted) -> Native API

Problem: The servicehost startup takes several seconds, which is too much. Especially when calling it from a multi threaded environment.

Is there a way to start this self hosted service on demand? My idea is something like 20 running service hosts (= processes), which get scaled up after for example 15 of these are in use. Remember, IIS hosted service is not an option, since IIS does not create such a servicehost in its own process (with his own memory) upon each request.

Comment: Then why do you think WCF is the way to go? Let your web app host SignalR host, and then all backend processes for model processing can connect to it as SignalR clients, and you can easily manage their connections.

Comment: Because it's the only way known to me when it comes to IPC between two processes (where one is using an unmanaged component). I'm not sure if SignalR helps me in this matter.